# How to keep YAML stuff (consumed by swagger) separate from docstring in our django project

Tags: django, swagger

My aim is to create swagger doc for our API written in  django-rest frameowrk. Right now I have to write the doc for each view inside the view, Could any one please tell me how to keep swagger related stuff (YAML stuff, which is written inside the docstring) in separate file. Because of addition of these docs related things make my file bulky.

Now it looks something like this:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def facebook(request):
"""
Facebook signup/login
---
parameters:
    - name: email
      type: string
      required: true
    - name: social_id
      type: string
      required: true
    - name: first_name
      type: string
      required: true
    - name: last_name
      type: string
      required: true

"""

email = request.POST.get("email")
social_id = request.POST.get("social_id")
first_name = request.POST.get("first_name")
last_name = request.POST.get("last_name")
```